# How do I get the ID of the X Window created by DirectFB?

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer, directfb

I'm developing for a program that uses DirectFB and GStreamer-0.10. I'm using `gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id()` from the `gstxoverlay` library of GStreamer to tell GStreamer to render to the window created by DirectFB. `gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id()` requires that I give it the ID of the X Window I want to render to, but I can't seem to find a way to get that from DirectFB.

Is there any way to get the X Window ID of the window created by DirectFB? If there isn't any easy way, is there a way to do some hackery with DirectFB's source files to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There must be `Window window;` like line somewhere in your code of `directfb`.  Try to expose it  to the gstreamer code.

Take the window handle from there and then you can use the below function

```
gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_X_OVERLAY(yoursinkvariable), (guintptr) windowhandle);
```

Not exactly in the way you were asking, but this might also resolve the problem.

Moreover, [gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id()](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-base-libs-0.10/gst-plugins-base-libs-gstxoverlay.html#gst-x-overlay-set-xwindow-id) is deprecated.

From the documentation,
**Warning**

`gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id` is deprecated and should not be used in newly-written code. Use `gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the deprecated function. As for the how to get the handle on the window, there isn't anything like `Window window;` in my DirectFB code. I believe I may have found a way to get it using the `IDirectFB` that's created, though. It looks a little something like [this](http://hastebin.com/xavitaxola.coffee). With that, I now get this error: **`X11/Core: Error! BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)`**. Does this mean I have the wrong handle, or is it because both GStreamer and DirectFB are trying to render to the same window at the same time?